# Write a function to delete a node (except the tail) in a singly linked list, given only access to that node

Tags: c++, memory-management, linked-list

```
struct ListNode {
      int val;
      ListNode *next;
      ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
};

void deleteNode(ListNode* node) { 
        *(node) = *(node->next);
}
```

I know that this would be the result

node = 3
deleteNode(node)
1->2->3->4->5
1->2->4->5

but where would this lead to a memory leak, the pointer would point to the new node, but would the int variable 3 still be floating around in memory somewhere? Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you learn about the `delete` operator to free memeory. Not just the `int` variable will be floating around but an entire `ListNode` object will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but would this lead to a memory leak

Yes.

> but would the int variable 3 still be floating around in memory somewhere?

No. The node which contains 4 is the one that is leaked, since it is the node containing 3 which was overwritten, and that is the node which was pointing to 4. The result would be like this:

```
      4  <--- this is the node which was leaked (since nothing points to it)
       \
        ->5
       /
1->2->4  <--- this is the node that used to contain 3
```

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to get rid of the node not having a pointer to its predecessor in the slist.

What you can do is move `->data` and `->next` from the `node->next` into the `node` and get rid of the `node->next`. It will be almost the same as requested — get rid of the data stored in the `node->data` and make list one element shorter.

The steps:

1. Dispose of `node->data`
2. Save the pointer to the node to be disposed `tmp = node->next`
3. Copy the next node stat into the current node `node->next = tmp->next; node->data = tmp->data`
4. Dispose of `tmp`

And the code (have not tried to compile):

```
node->val = 42; // dispose of node own data (not required for RAII fields)
ListNode* tmp = node->next;
*(node) = *(node->next);
delete tmp;
```

Comment: `node->val = 42;` is redundant.

Comment: @user2079303 - that's why the example has a commint stating precisely that